# Understanding SSMS error messages, regarding an INSERT error:

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

When I run an SSMS command to insert data, I get this error:

> *Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
>   Operand type clash: int is incompatible with ntext*

What is ment by `Level 16, State 2`

My insert is a standard insert:

```
insert into surveys 
values (18964, 'CD9E8ACE-0D22-4969-B324-620DAFF06F97', 19959, 486,  etc etc
```

How do I find where my error was ?

Comment: You should focus on the other part of the error, the one that says that *int is incompatible with ntext*. Basically, you are inserting an `INT` in a column of the type `NTEXT`. And, you should use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `NTEXT`, since that datatype is already deprecated. If you want a real answer, you need to post the table definition and the whole insert statement

Comment: What is the structure of `Surveys`? What is in "etc etc"?

Comment: @Lamak -  understood , will do

Comment: @Ciarán - ok, you mean data types - I see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are inserting value without single quote on a string column. String values need to be quoted as they are literal not identifiers.